# JavaScript execution order: why does this conditional execute after the code that follows it?

Tags: javascript, firefox, ecmascript-6, let, firefox-developer-tools

```
if(true) {
    let m = "yo";

    console.log(m);
}

console.log(m)
```

Output:

```
ReferenceError: m is not defined
yo
```

So the code on line 4 is being executed after the code on line 8.

Does my usage of `let` have anything to do with this?

*EDIT*: After reading comments I realised that this might be because of my runtime. Here's how I see it in Firefox nightly:

[image: firefox nightly let m]

*EDIT 2*: If this is indeed just my runtime, then are there implications for production code because of something like this? Inconsistent behaviour across browsers? How do I guard against that?

Comment: You're running this in Chrome?

Comment: [I can't reproduce that.](http://jsfiddle.net/nxzt5npp/) - and I'm viewing this in FF dev edition.

Comment: I get this behaviour in Firefox Nightly, console.

Comment: just tried and i am getting 
`yo` and then `ReferenceError: m is not defined` it seems ok

Comment: I get this behaviour in FF 41.0.2 OSX.

Comment: I'm Windows 7 running FF44.0a2 and I don't have the problem.

Comment: Please check the screenshot I've added. Perhaps this is OS *and* browser specific behaviour? I've also added a further question if that's the case.

Comment: Hm, `console.log` really got asynchronous now?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think the behaviour of the FF runtime is OK. A cursory glance the spec  (6.2.3.1 etc) indicates that the code should run line by line, until the second `console.log(m)` at which point a `ReferenceError` is thrown.

I suspect it only "looks funny" because of the order in which the console is choosing to render the first `console.log` and the exception message (it is the inverse of Chrome for instance).

Whether the rendering order to the console is considered a bug or not, I leave to others.

The following appears to confirm my analysis with the alert showing before the exception is logged.

```
if(true) {
    let m = "yo";

    alert(m);
}

console.log(m)
```

Comment: Could you confirm that this is a bug? I don't have the knowledge to infer what you're saying [I'm actually finding it hard to grasp :-)]. Perhaps I should file a report?

Comment: @adityamenon Throwing the reference error *early* and not executing the `if` and `console.log` at all *would* have been a bug. The code seems to execute fine, that the log is printed after the error is confusing but might be covered by the implementation of the `console` object. Yes, you should file a bug because this behaviour is quite unexpected, but not with ES6 compliancy but rather the devtools component. (And after you've done so, please link it here)

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1226585 I hope it doesn't suck as a bug report, too much.